# PHP Call to undefined function

Tags: php

I have a method named `getUserIds` in a class called `Db.php`.

```
public function getUserIds() {
    $connection = $this -> connect();
    return $this -> select("select distinct user_id from users");
}
```

When I call the function in a file located in the same folder as `Db.php` I get

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function getUserIds()

The file generating the error looks like this:

```
<?php
    require('Db.php');
    $db = new Db();
    $userIds = $db -> getUserIds();
    echo '<select>';
    echo '<option value="">Choose your User Id</option>
    while($userId = mysqli_fetch_assoc($userIds)) {
        echo "<option>$userId</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

Here is the contents of `Db.php`:

```
class Db {
    // The database connection
    protected static $connection;

    /**
     * Connect to the database
     * 
     * @return bool false on failure / mysqli MySQLi object instance on success
     */
    public function connect() {    
        // Try and connect to the database
        if(!isset(self::$connection)) {
            // Load configuration as an array. Use the actual location of your configuration file
            $config = parse_ini_file('./config.ini'); 
            self::$connection = new mysqli('localhost',$config['username'],$config['password'],$config['dbname']);
        }

        // If connection was not successful, handle the error
        if(self::$connection === false) {
            // Handle error - notify administrator, log to a file, show an error screen, etc.
            return false;
        }
        return self::$connection;
    }

    /**
     * Query the database
     *
     * @param $query The query string
     * @return mixed The result of the mysqli::query() function
     */
    public function query($query) {
        // Connect to the database
        $connection = $this -> connect();

        // Query the database
        $result = $connection -> query($query);

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch rows from the database (SELECT query)
     *
     * @param $query The query string
     * @return bool False on failure / array Database rows on success
     */
    public function select($query) {
        $rows = array();
        $result = $this -> query($query);
        if($result === false) {
            return false;
        }
        while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }
        return $rows;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch the last error from the database
     * 
     * @return string Database error message
     */
    public function error() {
        $connection = $this -> connect();
        return $connection -> error;
    }

    /**
     * Quote and escape value for use in a database query
     *
     * @param string $value The value to be quoted and escaped
     * @return string The quoted and escaped string
     */
    public function quote($value) {
        $connection = $this -> connect();
        return "'" . $connection -> real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }

    public function getUserIds() {
        $connection = $this -> connect();
        return $this -> select("select distinct user_id from users");
    }
}
```

Comment: plz provide content of Db.php file

Comment: Error message suggests that it could not create an instance of Db. What is the result of `var_dump($db);` immediately after creating it?

Comment: You are using `$this->select("select distinct user_id from users");` This assumes that theres a method called `select()` did you create such method? However the reason for your error is because your method `getUserIds()` is not reached at all. You need to make you are linking correctly to that `Db()` class file.

Comment: @CodeGodie, he wrote: "PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function getUserIds()".  So it would be better if he updates his question with contents of Db.php file.

Comment: I agree @num8er, just pointing out other errors that he/she may have. What do you think so far?

Comment: I think @JonKittell has forgot about his question. He does not want to react our comments (:

Comment: `getUserIds()` does not exist in your class, that is why youre getting that error

Comment: @num8er Give him a few mins to work out what to do to asnswer all the questions

Comment: @JonKittell In your OP you mention you have this function `getUserIds()` Where in your class is it located? Or where is it located at all? If it does not exist, you will get errors.

Comment: I just added the contents of `Db.php`

Comment: The method `getUserIds` not been set in class Db.php.

Comment: I copied the wrong file, sorry, I do have the method there

Comment: haha, what a waste of time you created.

Comment: You've copied the wrong file here? It seems to me that you are ```require```ing the wrong file in your code too...

Comment: provide your file structure. Where is the `Db.php` file located and where is the file where you have the `require` code is located?

Comment: All of the files are in `/var/www/html/talentportal/` directory on Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Comment: As already suggested, do a `var_dump` of `$db` as soon as you construct it. It is probably returning false, throwing an exception would make finding connection errors simpler.

Comment: _"All of the files"_ ? Can you list them so we know what files you are working with?

Comment: If you have multiple versions of the `DB` class, make sure to include the right one, if not, that is not the issue, as the error message would be very different if the DB class wasn't found.

Comment: @Pavlin I agree. You should direct the OP on how to create the exception.

Comment: There are only two files here, `Db.php` and 'profile-editor.php` in the directory `/var/www/html/talentportal/`

Comment: `var_dump($db)` ouputs this: `object(Db)#1 (0) { }`

Comment: @JonKittell If you want I can help you troubleshoot this remotely through Teamviewer. Let me know.

Comment: Ok, I send you message @CodeGodie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after fiddling around, the problem is that you are using a custom `select()` thus confusing you with the standard `sqli_fetch` method, and you don't have `error_reporting()` on so you werent able to see where the error came from. Hope all that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this exact problem, but it was because I failed to include "$this->" to point to the function in the same file.

EG:

`$Ts = CalculateTemperatureOffset($T);` //fails with error

`$Ts = $this->CalculateTemperatureOffset($T);` //works

Hopefully this helps other people who find run into something similar.